# Merge different web services to one port

Tags: port, port-forwarding, lighttpd

I have different web services running on different ports (on one Linux host):

```
https://host.com:101/app1/ (Flask)
https://host.com:102/app2/ (Ruby)
...
```

How can I access them through a common port (80), so the port could be hidden?

```
https://host.com/app1/
https://host.com/app2/
...
```

Content is HTML based, HTTPS is required. I would prefer lighttpd for the glue logic if possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you use a reverse proxy for.

Have the proxy listen on port 443 with a valid certificate, and configure your various backends with or without TLS security depending on your security goal.

I have no experience with lighttpd specifically, but a quick web search indicates that it should be possible for you to achieve something like this without resorting to other solutions like nginx or haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd can listen on port 443 and terminate the TLS.
lighttpd mod_proxy can be used to reverse proxy to backend HTTP (not HTTPS) services, typically running on the same local machine.
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy